# Scala Play DI issue: Cannot inject into field of class or object

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

My project has similar structure:

```
Application
|
|--> /ApplicationA
|   -> /app
|     ->Filters.scala
|     ->AuthenticationComponent.scala
|   -> /build.sbt
| 
|--> /ApplicationB
|   -> /app
|     ->Module.scala
|     ->VanillaAuthenticationUtil.scala
|   -> /build.sbt
|
|-> /conf
|-> /build.sbt
```

The code of *Module.scala* is listed:

```
class Module extends AbstractModule  {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[AuthenticationUtil])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("authUtil"))
      .to(classOf[VanillaAuthenticationUtil]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Also, *ApplicationA*  does not know about *ApplicationB* and *ApplicationB* depends on *ApplicationA*.

The code of *Filters.scala* and *AuthenticationComponent.scala* also listed:

```
class Filters @Inject()(corsFilter: CORSFilter) extends HttpFilters {
  @Inject
  @Named("authUtil")
  var authUtil:AuthenticationUtil = _
  def filters = Seq(corsFilter, authUtil)
}

class AuthenticationComponent   {
  @Inject
  @Named("authUtil")
  var authUtil:AuthenticationUtil = _
  def getAuthUtil():AuthenticationFilter ={

  println(authUtil == null)
  authUtil
  }
}
```

So, when I'm calling *getAuthUtil* from *AuthenticationComponent* it says that  authUtil is equals null, but in case of *Filters* it's false. The same situation is when I'm trying to inject into scala object I'm also receiving null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend mixing field and constructor injection. Move it to a constructor param, and it will probably work.